# Calculation with RESTful web service with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, rest

I am now making some RESTful web services with MySQL database. I used NetBeans to create the resources of RESTful service with MySQL, and now I can now use GET and POST/PUT to list and add/modify data entities in the MySQL server.

Currently, I wish to make some calculations right after a client makes the POST activities, then the posted data with calculated results will be inserted into the MySQL database. I am very new to this, I guess I need to add some functions and call them to calculate but I don't know where and how to do that : (

Could any one help me on this issue? Thanks a lot in advance! : )

Comment: what language are you using to create the rest functions?

Comment: OH I am using NetBeans/JAVA : )

Comment: Sounds like you're using some code generation feature from your IDE (NetBeans) to create an http interface on a SQL database. If that is right, can you link to a web page 'help' resource about this feature?

Comment: You may want to download and read the JavaEE tutorial here http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7627/giqaa?a=view

Comment: thanks a lot :) i am now doing very well : )